# Copying cells with content in a column then moving to the next column I determine using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I have about 4 sheets lets call them A, A1, B, and B1 where I have content in different columns that I need copied to a new sheet lets call C in 1 column.

I want to copy all the content in specific columns for all four sheets but ignoring cells that are empty and once it copies all the content from the first column in the first sheet A, it will do the same for A1, and B and B1.

I want all the copied content to be posted into a new column on a new sheet lets call C, one after the other without skipping rows due to the empty cells that are not copied, and have the content be automatically placed in order on the new page.

Comment: OK, great - that's a statement of requirements. In general, readers would like to see an attempt as well. If you have such a thing, please edit it into your question, using the formatting tools provided; if you have not made a start on it, would you give that a go first?

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try if you haven't already:
In your workbook, Try the record the Macro feature, carry out all the actions you have mentioned above, then stop the macro recorder.

Go to the back-end where this code resides (Press Alt+F11) and give an attempt to  understand the code and make it dynamic.

If and when you run into trouble then please do come here and post your work. We will be happy to help you make this code dynamic and make sure your solution works.

Please give it a try...

Regards,
Yash